# Clear `QGraphicsView` immediately in Qt <= 5.12

Tags: python, pyqt5

The given code below is derived from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59120337/why-does-pyqt-sometimes-crash-on-exit) on SO. It displays a `QMainWindow` with 4 `QGraphicsView` to draw with the mouse in it and a `QPushButton` to clear the 4 `QGraphicsView`.

There is a [`clear()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html#clear) method in `QPainterPath` class, but it *was introduced in Qt **5.13*** and I'm using Qt **5.12**. So I wrote my own method to clear the views and its paths.

Drawing works fine and clicking on the `Clear` button does not cause an error, but the views are only cleared at the next time drawing in and not immediately.

What's a better solution to clear the views immediately?

---

### main.py

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsPathItem
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainterPath, QPen
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

# Based on code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44248794/7481773


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        loadUi("mainwindow.ui", self)

        self.layouts = (self.verticalLayout_top_left, self.verticalLayout_top_right,
                        self.verticalLayout_bottom_left, self.verticalLayout_bottom_right)

        self._views = []

        for layout in self.layouts:
            graphics_view = GraphicsView()
            self._views.append(graphics_view)
            layout.addWidget(graphics_view)

        self.clear_button.clicked.connect(self.clear_views)

    def clear_views(self):
        for view in self._views:
            view.clear_view()


class GraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.start = None
        self.end = None

        self.setScene(QGraphicsScene())
        self.path = QPainterPath()
        self.item = GraphicsPathItem()
        self.scene().addItem(self.item)

        self.contents_rect = self.contentsRect()
        self.setSceneRect(0, 0, self.contents_rect.width(), self.contents_rect.height())
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

    def clear_view(self):
        # self.path.clear()  # Qt 5.13
        self.path = QPainterPath()
        self.scene().update()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.start = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
        self.path.moveTo(self.start)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.end = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
        self.path.lineTo(self.end)
        self.start = self.end
        self.item.setPath(self.path)


class GraphicsPathItem(QGraphicsPathItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pen = QPen()
        pen.setColor(Qt.black)
        pen.setWidth(5)
        self.setPen(pen)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    app.exec_()
    del main_window, app


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

### mainwindow.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Paint and Clear</string>
  </property>
  <property name="locale">
   <locale language="English" country="UnitedKingdom"/>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_top_left"/>
    </item>
    <item row="0" column="1">
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_top_right"/>
    </item>
    <item row="2" column="0">
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_bottom_left"/>
    </item>
    <item row="2" column="1">
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_bottom_right"/>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0" colspan="2">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="clear_button">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Clear</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>24</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even using the `clear()` method does not imply that the view is cleaned but you have to set the path in the item. Going to the problem, an equivalent method is to establish a new `QPainterPath`, in addition it is not necessary to call the `update()` method of the scene. The use of `clear()` or set an empty `QPainterPath` are equivalent from the python side, but from the C++ side it causes the same memory that optimizes the application to be reused.

```py
def clear_view(self):
    self.path = QPainterPath()
    self.item.setPath(self.path)
```

If you want to have compatibility for both versions you can use try-except:

```py
def clear_view(self):
    try:
        self.path.clear()
    except AttributeError as e:
        self.path = QPainterPath()
    self.item.setPath(self.path)
```